# How do I get the RGB value of a material in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rgb

I have a script attached to a cube and I don't know how to get the RGB value from it's material. So far I've fetched the renderer with `Renderer rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();`. Any idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity c# is rusty but try this, hope it works.

```
Color32 objColor;

objColor = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color;
print(objColor.r + " "+ objColor.g + " "+ objColor.b+ " "+ objColor.a + " ");
```

Get back to me if it doesn't work

Comment: It works great and also supports alpha values (which I forgot to ask for), thank you!